TCL using Regex to extract specific pattern word in a string
$I'm trying to extract specific word in TCL using regex that have below criteria

Begin with letter "K"
Second letter is either A or H or N or Z or R
followed by letters
followed by dash "-"
followed by letters
ending with 2 numbers


set title "reserved for KNBCDEF-ABCD01"
set greptitle [regexp -all -inline {\mK[AHNZR][A-Za-z]*-[0-9]{2}\M} $title]
send_user "Matched patterns: $greptitle\n"

trying above code but gave empty output.
Extracted word from string(s) might be in any below format as long as it matched above criteria
KNBCDEF-ABCD01 or KAXXG-YYUU54 or KRBEF-ZZ654 etc.

Your regular expression does not include part 5.

It would probably help to use extended syntax in this case so you could comment each bit of the RE to say what it is matching.

Shall the second part really match lower case as well?

you were almost correct you dont need to use \m or \M in your regexp pattern
set title "reserved for KNBCDEF-ABCD01"

set greptitle [regexp {\s+K[AHNZR]\w+-\w+\d\d} $title match]

the greptitle contains 1 if pattern match else 0
puts "Matched patterns: $greptitle\n"

match has your pattern
puts $match


With a more complex regular expression, it can help a lot to use extended syntax:
set title "reserved for KNBCDEF-ABCD01"
set greptitle [regexp -all -inline {(?x)
    \mK         # 1. Begin with letter "K"
    [AHNZR]     # 2. Second letter is either A or H or N or Z or R
    [A-Za-z]*   # 3. followed by letters
    -           # 4. followed by dash "-"
    [A-Za-z]*   # 5. followed by letters (you were missing this bit)
    [0-9]{2}\M  # 6. ending with 2 numbers
} $title]
send_user "Matched patterns: $greptitle\n"

That you can put comments in with that syntax is very helpful; you can list out the bits you are looking for and what they mean. That helps you avoid silly mistakes like leaving one piece out.

using the match variables, so is there a or function between patterns or how does it work.?
